# Regex query for capturing a group of words

Tags: python, regex

I want to create a regex query to capture exact words in documents. The words I want to capture are  `["Lorem", "Ipsum", "Dolor", "Sit Amet", "Consectetur Adipiscing"]`. The source text is something like this:

```
string = "
text before ....
Draft Report 








Lorem



Lorem



Lorem



Ipsum



Dolor



Dolor



Sit Amet



Consectetur Adipiscing



Consectetur Adipiscing



Sit Amet







Reason for test: Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
the text goes on..."
```

However, I only want to capture the words after The "Report" and before the "Reason". Also note that there may be words other than "Reason" after the desired capture group so it might be something like this:

```
string = "
text before ....
Draft Report 








Lorem



Lorem



Lorem



Ipsum



Dolor



Dolor



Sit Amet



Consectetur Adipiscing



Consectetur Adipiscing



Sit Amet







Another probability for this test: Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
the text goes on..."
```

I want to extract a text from the above samples so that the result would be:

```
extracted_text = "
Lorem



Lorem



Lorem



Ipsum



Dolor



Dolor



Sit Amet



Consectetur Adipiscing



Consectetur Adipiscing



Sit Amet"
```

Or a list like: `["Lorem", "Lorem", "Lorem", "Ipsum", "Dolor", "Dolor", "Sit Amet", "Consectetur Adipiscing", "Consectetur Adipiscing", "Sit Amet"]`

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can first extract everything between "Report" and "Reason" with `(?s)Report(.*?)Reason`, then extract only needed words with `\b(Lorem|Ipsum|Dolor|Sit Amet|Consectetur Adipiscing)\b`

Comment: there are some other documents that use various words different than Reason at the end of the desired section.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you do not want to use regex for your use case. Assuming the words you are looking for are separated by three new lines then the following should produce your wanted output

```py
'\n\n\n'.join(string.split('\n\n\n')[1:-1])
```

or if you wanted it as the list you described, then something like this:

```py
list(map(lambda y: y.strip('\n'), filter(lambda y: y != '', string.split('\n\n\n')[1:-1])))
```

Comment: The problem is that your suggested method also captures the rest of the text where \n\n\n has also occured

Comment: @MRF is there text with three new lines above report or below reason? If that is the case you could scope your split to only the select lines with `string = string[string.index('Report') : string.index('Reason')]`

Comment: there are some other documents that use various words different than Reason at the end of the desired section.